# How many 6 character passwords are possible if letters cannot be repeated but digits CAN be?

Tags: combinatorics

A computer system uses passwords that have six characters, and each character is
one of the 26 letters (a-z) or 10 integers (0-9). The first character has to be a letter.
The passwords are not case sensitive. How many contain no repeated letters but can contain repeated integers?

I could do this question easily if neither letters **nor** integers could be repeated but having one allow repetition and the other not has thrown me off.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You could consider cases, depending on how many letters are in the password.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited to Joffan's input*

How I would guess to approach this, I am also pretty new to combinatorics.

For the first space you have 26 options since there is NOT case sensitive.

(26 option)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)

Now for the remaining five slots you would have six possible cases.

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\text{# Letters (after first)} & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{# Numbers} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

There is another layer to think about say in the case of three letter and two numbers, you know have five slots and three slots to place letters so you have ${5 \choose 3}$ ways of picking positions for letters and for each of the positions you would have 25 options for the first slots since one letter is taken for the fist slot, 24 options for the second and 23 options for the third slots, as for the last two number slots you would have $10\cdot 10$ options.

I would then take a guess that the final number would be
$26 \cdot \left({5 \choose 5} 
\cdot \frac{25!}{(25-5)!} \cdot 10^0 + {5 \choose 4} 
\cdot\frac{25!}{(25-4)!} \cdot 10^1 + {5 \choose 3} 
\cdot\frac{25!}{(25-3)!} \cdot 10^2 +{5 \choose 2} 
\cdot\frac{25!}{(25-2)!} \cdot 10^3 +{5 \choose 1} 
\cdot\frac{25!}{(25-1)!} \cdot 10^4 +{5 \choose 0} 
\cdot\frac{25!}{(25)!} \cdot 10^5\right)$

or rather
$26 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{5}\left({{5 \choose k} 
\cdot\frac{25!}{(25-k)!}} \cdot 10^{5-k}\right)$.

And as a final summary since the multiplicative factor of 26 distributes to all summands we end up with

$$\sum_{k=0}^{5}\left({{5 \choose k} 
\cdot\frac{26!}{(25-k)!}} \cdot 10^{5-k}\right)$$

This is my first time posting so I know my answer is poorly formatted, I cannot fully verify my answer but this is what I would turn in if I had to give it an attempt. I would love to get some feedback on this as I recently started self learning combinatorics.

Comment: I take the requirement "passowrds are not case sensitive" to mean that you only choose from one case since "A"="a" - so $26$ choices rather than $52$. Also: you lost your multiplier when you move to the summation, but **most importantly** you should use nPr rather than nCr since letter order remains important. And remember, you can't repeat the first letter either.

Comment: So it would be (26P6) + (26P5 * $10^1$) + (26P4 * $10^2$) + (26P3 * $10^3$) + (26P2 * $10^4$) + (26P1 * $10^5$)?

Comment: Yeah you are right Joffan I was confusing permutations and different subsets, I also read misinterpreted the case sensitivity. 

I should have pondered more on this, sorry if I confused you Ben

Comment: @Joffan Could you add some verification to this. Perhaps if you could restructure my answer if it is valid. Thank you for the feedback, I will think my answers through better before answering in the future.

Comment: Looks good - I added back a couple of factorial marks that got lost.